# HTTPApi + Serverless Framework + API Gateway CORS not working

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

I have an HTTPApi API Gateway created with the Serverless Framework. But for some routes, the CORS is not working.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  timeout: 29
  httpApi:
    cors:
      allowedOrigins:
        - '*'
      allowedMethods:
        - GET
        - OPTIONS
        - POST
        - PUT
        - DELETE
      allowedHeaders:
        - Content-Type
        - X-Amz-Date
        - Authorization
        - X-Api-Key
        - X-Amz-Security-Token
        - X-Amz-User-Agent
        - X-Transaction-Key
        - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

I tried setting the `cors:true` option on the provider but still doesnt work.
This is the response returned on all routes wether it is 4xx or 2xx codes.

```
return {
    statusCode: StatusCode,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(Res, null, 2),
  };
```

If I check the console [I can see that the options are indeed applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ecr.png)
However, [some routes actually work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4DeV.png) 
And  [some others don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MnRs.png), the ones that don't work have the `X-Transaction-Key` header and the `OPTIONS` does not return the `access-control-allow-headers: authorization,content-type,x-amz-date,x-amz-security-token,x-amz-user-agent,x-api-key,x-transaction-key` header

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to API gateway in AWS and enable CORS on all the resource

Comment: API gateway did not work for me as expected, so I ended up using the API or code level passing of allowed origins and headers, but anyone can please point to the downside of this, would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a similar problem. After 3 days of pulling my hair. I have found my problem. Everything was ok except, **In my client, there were few wrong URLs(spelling mistakes) pointing to my server API.** This is why few API was ok and few of them not working properly.

After fixing to the right URL everything is ok. **Here is my learning,** hope someday it will help others:

1. Check you're serverless.yml file's cors section, here is an example

   ```
    cors:
       origin: '*'
       headers:
         - Content-Type
         - X-Amz-Date
         - Authorization
         - X-Api-Key
         - X-Amz-Security-Token
       allowCredentials: false
   ```
2. Check Lamdba for proper response header as question contains

**Additional Tools for troubleshooting:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/support-case-browser-har-file/
- https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/

Hope it will be helpful, Thanks!

Happy Coding

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I discovered the problem later and solved it the same way but didn't update my question. I think that this happens whenever non-standard or custom headers are added to the request. My problem was that I had an additional header

Comment: For me the problem was an extra / in the url!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Please check whether you are sending all the correct **Headers**. If any additional header you send and don't fine tune the cors config you will get a CORS error

For me I had a typo with **Authorization** header. Took me 3+ days to figure it out lol!

Please check this link for detailed documentation and how to fine tune cors for httpAPi
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried fixing the 'cors: true' value in the function event as in [Serverless with cors](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide) ?